# If I remove public IP from D365FO cloud hosted VM then does it impact communication with LCS?

Tags: dynamics-365

The requirement is to enable Dev VMs access only through Azure Bastion and remove public IPs of Dev VMs.

In this context, it would be helpful if some insights can be provided with respect to the communication with LCS e.g.

- how LCS connect with DEV VMs behind the scene?
- applying packages upgrades to Dev VMs thru LCS, is it a valid use case?
- after removing public IP, can LCS be used to apply package upgrades?

As per the below resource LCS uses WinRM ports of VM but does not mention whether ports are accessed using public IP or private endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/secure-developer-vm

Thank you for any suggestion in this regard.